# Magento - Base tax removed, store tax applied

Tags: magento

We have multiple websites, each with it's own base-currency and tax-rules.
The prices is entered in admin including tax, in each stores own currency.

The problem is that magento takes the entered price, then remove the tax according to the "default"-store, then apply the tax for the correct store.

**Example:**
The price is 33 in admin.
The "default" tax-rate is 25%. 33 / 1,25 = 26,4
Tax-rate in germany is 19%. 26,4 * 1,19 = 31,416
**31,42** is the displayed price in fronted, when it should be 33.

**Config values of interest:**
Tax Calculation Based On: *shipping address*
Catalog Prices: *Including tax*
Default Country: *Sweden (Default)*
Default Country: *Germany (website)*
Display Product Prices In Catalog: *Including tax*

Can this behavior be configured? Is there a reliable workaround. I'm afraid that we do not have the option to change all the prices to excluding tax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe it, i found the solution right after posting the question:

The setting "*System -> Configuration -> Sales - Shipping settings -> Origin*" was still set to Sweden. I changed that to match the tax-rule that should be applied, Germany in my case.

It's not at all obvious what this setting does, but it works..